# Add a column that sum the number of sessions per user in R

Tags: r, data-mining, calculated-columns

I starting to data-mine a mobile application, 
and I have a database that looks like this:

```
Database
UserId         Hour         Date
01                18           01.01.2016
01                18           01.01.2016
01                14           02.01.2016
01                14           03.01.2016
02                21           03.01.2016
02                08           05.01.2016
02                08           05.01.2016
03                23           05.01.2016
```

I would like to add a new column to this database that sums the number of different days the user has been using the application,
In this database for example UserId#01 has been on the platform in three different days,

Expected data outcomes like this:

```
Database
UserId         Hour         Date                 NumDates
01                18           01.01.2016        3
01                18           01.01.2016        3
01                14           02.01.2016        3
01                14           03.01.2016        3 
02                21           03.01.2016        2
02                08           05.01.2016        2
02                08           05.01.2016        2
03                23           05.01.2016        1
```

So far I have used this command:

```
Database["NumDates"] % group_by(UserId) %>% summarise(NumDates = length(unique(Date)))
```

But it tells me that that it is creating only 5000 lines (the number of different users in my database) when I need +600,000 (the number of sessions in my database)

If somebody could help me with this, it will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `uniqueN` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(Database)[, NumDates := uniqueN(Date) , by = UserId]
Database
#   UserId Hour       Date NumDates
#1:      1   18 01.01.2016        3
#2:      1   18 01.01.2016        3
#3:      1   14 02.01.2016        3
#4:      1   14 03.01.2016        3
#5:      2   21 03.01.2016        2
#6:      2    8 05.01.2016        2
#7:      2    8 05.01.2016        2
#8:      3   23 05.01.2016        1
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use n_distict in dplyr

```
library("dplyr")
database<- data.frame(UserId = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3), Hour = c(18,18,14,14,21,8,8,23), Date = c("01.01.2016","01.01.2016","02.01.2016","03.01.2016","03.01.2016","05.01.2016","05.01.2016","05.01.2016"))
database %>% group_by(userId) %>% mutate(NumDates = n_distinct(Date))
```

the result is as follows

```
   UserId  Hour       Date NumDates
    (dbl) (dbl)     (fctr)    (int)
1      1    18 01.01.2016        3
2      1    18 01.01.2016        3
3      1    14 02.01.2016        3
4      1    14 03.01.2016        3
5      2    21 03.01.2016        2
6      2     8 05.01.2016        2
7      2     8 05.01.2016        2
8      3    23 05.01.2016        1
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want `summarise` here but `mutate`. `summarise` will give you one row by distinct value of the column you grouped by, while `mutate` will just add another column and preserving existing ones.